# How to remove requests from python and install in pip

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, python3, pip

I need to reference to requests in pip but it is already installed in python.

```
 Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.18.4)
```

How can I change requests to pip?

- Version of Ubuntu: 18.04.2 LTS
- Version of python3: 3.6.8
- Version of pip: pip 19.1.1 from /home/biggi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Running my python script I get the error

```
import requests 
ImportError: No module named requests
```

---

When I try to: `sudo pip install requests`

```
The directory '/home/biggi/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is
not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please
check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip
with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. The directory
'/home/biggi/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the
current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the
permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo,
you may want sudo's -H flag. Requirement already satisfied: requests
in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages Requirement already satisfied:
urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in
./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests) Requirement
already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in
./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests) Requirement
already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in
./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests) Requirement
already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in
./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
```

Comment: someone who could help me with that?

Comment: May be the module requests is installed in Python3 but not installed in Python2 and may be when you run your code, you run it in Python2.
So try running your code with this command: `python3 your_script.py`

Comment: Please always use **code formatting** for posting terminal output, *never blockquote*. It destroys the original text structure and makes the information hard to read. Also [edit] your question to add more information, the answer section is for solutions only. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo -H pip install requests` solved the problem:

> Collecting requests   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (57kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.3MB/s Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests)   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/60/247f23a7121ae632d62811ba7f273d0e58972d75e58a94d329d51550a47d/urllib3-1.25.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (150kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 2.7MB/s Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/1b/b853c7a9d4f6a6d00749e94eb6f3a041e342a885b87340b79c1ef73e3a78/certifi-2019.6.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (157kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 2.4MB/s Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (133kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 3.0MB/s Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>   (from requests) Installing collected packages: urllib3, certifi,
>   chardet, requests Successfully installed certifi-2019.6.16
>   chardet-3.0.4 requests-2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.3